# Payment status remains "Pending"

Tags: paypal

I integrated PayPal in my web shop in order to allow instant payments with automatic product delivery (already had this before but only with instant wire transfers via sofort.com). I integrated it with the help of the example provided by PayPal (I'm using ReviewOrder.php, GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment).

It's working great if they pay with PayPal balance or a linked credit card. However, some customers from Germany don't have balance in their accounts but only a bank account linked to their account. The payments go through and they receive their product, however I noticed the payment status would remain "Pending" for 1 month and change to "Expired" afterwards, so effectively no money arrives.

Why is this happening? Or is there any way to deny such payments? (Payments from backup funds)

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I managed to find a solution to this odd problem after all.

It turned out I had the following code in my implementation where I actually initialized the payment process:

```
$_REQUEST['paymentType'] = "Order";
```

This was a mistake though, since this payment type won't place a hold on the funds and if the DoCapture call is never called this payment will remain pending for about one month and then expire entirely (as described in my question, so this is what actually happened to me). The bad thing is that it's impossible for such payments to even accept them manually from within PayPal (not even the local PayPal phone support was able/wanted to accept these payments for unknown reasons because they told me they'd come up with a solution and contact me via Email within 24 hours but they never did).

So in order to fix this issue I changed the payment type to Sale which instantly captures the payment rather than waiting for sort of approval or a capture call. It worked fine for two weeks now and I think I'll leave it like this now.

```
$_REQUEST['paymentType'] = "Sale";
```

I lost about 110€ because this stupidly trivial detail but at least it's working fine now and I was able to re-enable PayPal as a payment form. I hope they'll at least add an option to manually accept these payments if the DoCapture call was not implemented because it worked fine without it for most of the payments as well and after all this is still about real money, so this absolutely would be an essential thing to have....

Answer (score 1):

Its hare to day with out looking at the transaction specifically.  But there are several things that can cause your payment to be pending, such as your preferences that you may have set in the account.  Check to make sure you dont have your preferences set to ask me before accepting a payment in a currency that you do not hold.  Did the buyer pay with an eCheck?  If so, it could be waiting for the payment to clear.  If this is in the sandbox, you have to manually clear the payment.  If you are still not able to determine the cause of the pending payment, if you provide the transaction id, I will check it on my end.

Comment: I've got no idea. But I guess he just used to send the payment via a German bank account again. But I guess it's either sort of a wrong setting or wrong implementation of the API. There were about 10 transactions with the same problem (which already expired since we had PayPal disabled for a month now), but this is the latest ID: O-9PR33160TM334903W

Answer (score 0):

This can happen also if you are trying to accept a payment in a different currency of your account. To avoid that you must create a "PayPal balance" in the currency of the payment.
IPN is also giving hints on the pending reason in this case:
[pending_reason] => multi_currency